# Angular Pre-Bootstrap animation possible to have on another thread or run asynchronously?

Tags: html, css, angular

Is there a way to show the pre-loading animation on a separate thread until angular loads completely?
I am finding that the animation is very jittery and not smooth. I looked in the console and the animation is only updated between loading scripts. If a script is taking a while to load then the animation freezes

For example this animation freezes when the following scripts are loading
main.js, styles.js and especially vendor.js where it freezes from 1 to 2 seconds.
As shown in the following photo

[image: Scripts]

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>My Application</title>
      <base href="/">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <style>
        app-root {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;

        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: -apple-system,
          BlinkMacSystemFont,
          "Segoe UI",
          Roboto,
          Oxygen-Sans,
          Ubuntu,
          Cantarell,
          Helvetica,
          sans-serif;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      }

      body {
        transition: opacity 0 ease-in-out 1s;
        background: darkgray;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      @keyframes dots {
        50% {
          transform: translateY(-.4rem);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateY(0);
        }
      }
      .d {
        animation: dots 1.5s ease-out infinite;
      }
      .d-2 {
        animation-delay: .9s;
      }

      .d-3 {
        animation-delay: 1s;
      }
    </style>
    Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span>
  </app-root>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you please add a stackblitz sample?? so we'll see exactly your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using transforms, which in theory should be using a separate thread from the UI, so it shouldn't be blocked by the JS.

Within the CSS you could try using the `will-change` property for your animation List the specific properties that will change like so:

```
.element {
    will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

`will-change` indicates that an element’s properties will change so that the browser can make appropriate preparations.

> using will-change consumes resources, be warned that overuse can lead to further performance problems. Putting it before every animation by default isn’t recommended.